# extend properties of input element in angular 2

Tags: angular, visual-studio

I have an `<input>` component in angular 2 which I need to extend its properties...

*controltextbox.component.html*

```
<input type="text" />
```

and I have to make sure that those who consume it in the future will be able to know its new properties without having to enter in the ".ts" file, but simply using the visual studio 2017 intellisense. eg:

```
<input type="text" [newProperty1]="true" [newProperty2]="data" [newProperty3]="" />
```

or

```
<input type="text" [textboxClass]="" />
```

What's the best way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

intellisense is about IDE not about code itself.

In your case intellisense can be expanded with vs code:

https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/4369